# Laravel: compile node_modules to app.js and app.css

Tags: node-modules, npm-run

I've created a new Laravel-project using composer

```
./composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist ProjectName
```

Next, I've added the required packages through npm. I've already noticed the `--save` switch is necessary to make it work correctly:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install bootstrap --save
npm install font-awesome --save
```

When I show the packages in this directory:

```
npm list --depth=0
@ /var/www/ProjectName
├── axios@0.16.2
├── bootstrap@3.3.7
├── bootstrap-sass@3.3.7
├── cross-env@5.0.5
├── font-awesome@4.7.0
├── jquery@3.2.1
├── laravel-mix@1.4.5
├── lodash@4.17.4
└── vue@2.4.4
```

Nothing is listed as extraneous.

Now, I'm trying to compile these assets (js and css) into 2 files, which are easy to include in the blade-template.
The docs say I have to use `npm run dev`, but this fails with the most cryptic message you can ever imagine.

```
events.js:141
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^
```

**Extras**

- Call stack:

  ```
  Error: spawn node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ENOENT
      at exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:189:32)
      at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:363:16)
      at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:511:9)
      at process._tickCallback (node.js:425:17)
      at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
      at startup (node.js:140:18)
      at node.js:1043:3
  ```
- The `npm run dev` command results in following command:

  ```
  cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
  ```
- Versions:

  ```
  npm ERR! node -v v4.8.2
  npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
  ```

I've put the entire output online as well:
[output](https://pieterjan.pro/output.txt)

Why isn't it possible to compile the assets? How can I fix this?

### EDIT:

All right found it!

somehow i reinstalled nodejs to not have the legacy-version.
These are the commmands I ran:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get -y install nodejs
sudo apt-get install dh-autoreconf
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
npm install bootstrap --save
npm list --depth=0
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the contents of node_modules/

```
rm -Rfv your_project_path/node_modules/
```

then

```
npm install
```

Let me know if it helps.